# Automatically capture photo and record video without interact click button on Default Camera

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

Can we capture or record video on Default camera in android? Without interaction camera click button or Without using Surfaceview or Custom Camera.

Comment: There is no "Default camera in android". There are ~26,000 Android device models, with dozens or hundreds of pre-installed camera apps. The user can also install other camera apps from the Play Store or elsewhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare So how can achieve this functionality

Comment: The only way that you will be able to have interaction-free recording of video will be if you do it yourself, using Android's Camera2 API or a library that wraps around it (Google's CameraX, Fotoapparat, CameraKit-Android, etc.).